# Algolia Record count surge

Tags: algolia

[image: Record count mismatch]

When uploaded records from Admin Panel today and found a rare increase in the stats which cant able to understand. Have uploaded json with 113 records but in stats it displays as 298,000 !!! Cant able to understand why it is happening. Is it a problem in Algolia and is it advisable to trust Algolia Billing, as we cant able to find any Ticket support for Algolia too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops problem is CSV file which was uploaded. Microsoft Excel generated CSV file with empty comma for more than a million lines (just comma alone without data). And when uploaded it seems Algolia confused and billed.

Answer (score 0):

The information about the number of records should be good, if you click on the day view on the up right corner:

[image: graph view]

You should see a spike in the number of records. You can also check the number of operation done during the same period of time in the graph below, it should be higher to this number of record.

Best regards